# Not able to Run React native IOS App on new Xcode version 13

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have upgraded Xcode version13 .I started getting error trying to running ios app and the build always gets failed .

if I choose the option legacy build System it throws error :
**The Legacy Build System will be removed in a future release. You can configure the selected build system and this deprecation message in File > Workspace Settings**.

If I choose New Build System It throws error : **Multiple commands produce '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-fqdjurlyjvhihgfubhiaayzhaadv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproject.app/AntDesign.ttf':

1. Target 'Project' (project 'Project') has copy command from '/Users/username/Desktop/Project/employee-mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' to '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-fqdjurlyjvhihgfubhiaayzhaadv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproject.app/AntDesign.ttf'
2. That command depends on command in Target 'Project' (project 'project Name'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
   **

what all I have tried :

1. deleted repo and cloned it again
2. did pod install again
3. removed some file from Build Phase => copy bundle Resource
4. Delete Drived data

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Choose the option "**Don not show a diagnostic issue about build system depreciation** "